# Which piece of ['content'] is relevant in $page when using hook_page_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Background:
I'm building a site that collects information from a user with a webform, uses the values collected to calculate some results, then uses the results to pick a suggested solution from a list (or complain that the program can't provide an answer from the provided parameters).

When the user clicks submit, the calculations get done via hook_webform_submission_presave(), and I store the calculation results in elements of the $_SESSION array (a capacity figure, coded with negative values for the "can't provide an answer" case mentioned above), and a string with a suggested model number if there is a solution. After the webform submit happens, Drupal's going to link to a new (standard content page), which (I had intended) was going to get changed by hook_page_alter().  So, now to the problem(s):

I had planned to have hook_page_alter go looking for an element of the plain content page (the string xxxxxx), and substitute for that string what the page actually should contain (either a note about the solution selected, or an error message asking the user to either try again, or get in touch with us by e-mail or some such).

The problem:
hook_page_alter() receives a massive array, $page, to manipulate.  The part of it that I'm operating on is $page['content], but even within that, my trigger string ('xxxxxx') occurs frequently (21 times, when I dump $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]).

What's even more interesting (to me, anyway) is that if I substitute the string 'yyyyyy' for 'xxxxxx' with the following code (yes, it's ugly, but it's late at night, and I'm in full debug mode here :

```
    $xx = $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][5]['body']['#object'];
    $yy = $xx->body['und'][0]['value'];
    $zz = str_replace("xxxxxx", "yyyyyy", $yy);
    $xx->body['und'][0]['value'] = $zz;
    // dpr() below is like print_r, from the handy dandy Drupal 'devel' module
    dpr($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][5]);
```

Going through the output of dpr() and looking at what actually gets rendered is interesting - by that little substitution, the number of occurrences of xxxxxx gets reduced to 11, and (even more interesting !) I find 8 occurrences of yyyyyy.  Unfortunately, the page renders unaffected by my substitution - the xxxxxx is still present.

What I'm interested in finding is which of the $page array elements is the one that gets rendered - I'll figure that out tomorrow, I guess, by elimination (and will post when I find it).  Any hints from you wizards out there ?

Also, is there a more "drupal-esque" way that I should be looking at to do this whole thing ?

The second problem is of more academic interest - how did my change to one element of this part of the $page array:
        $xx->body['und'][0]['value'] = $zz;
get replicated to the other 7 places that I found it ?
Insights ?  Comments ?  (be polite, please - I've been working with Drupal for about 6 months, but have been writing software for much longer than that)

Thanks in advance,

Derek

Comment: Primary problem solved ...the content that gets rendered to the page is here:   
$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][5]['body'][0]['#markup']

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title, it's `$page` itself. 
`hook_page_alter` has one argument and that argument is an array of regions at its first level. 
So if you named the argument as $page, `$page['content']` is the content if the content region (don't be confused with this 
content" part. Other elements are content, too).

It's hard to tell what is the exact problem without seeing your entire `hook_page_alter` function.

And as a side note, I would recommend not using that hook for this case. For me, it sounds like there should be a better (and cheaper in terms of server resource usage) solution.
Webform is yet another Drupal form so all hook_form_alter stuff applies here. 
You can add extra submit handlers to existing webform and even new pages in menu registry (reserve some path or a set of paths using wildcards) so there is really no need to use `hook_page_alter` for your case IMO.

PS: Listen to [this podcast from LullaBot guys](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/podcasts/moshe-weitzman-page-rendering-drupal-7).